# Requirement is to write trigger to restrict duplicates for week

Tags: before-trigger

Requirement: Restrict duplicate accounts for current week.

> Error : Compile Error: Unexpected token 'weekStart'. at line 16 column 121

Trigger Code:

```
trigger DuplicateTrigger on Account (before insert)
{

    Set<String> setName = new Set<String>();
    DateTime myDate = system.now();
    DateTime weekStart = myDate.toStartofWeek();
    DateTime weekEnd = weekStart.addDays(7);

    For(Account acc : trigger.new)
    {
        setName.add(acc.name);
    }

    if(setName.size() > 0)
    {
        List<Account> lstAccount = [select Name, id, CreatedDate from account where name in :setName AND CreatedDate >= weekStart AND CreatedDate < weekEnd];

        Map<String ,Account> mapNameWiseAccount = new Map<String,Account>();
        For(Account acc: lstAccount)
        {
            mapNameWiseAccount.put(acc.name ,acc);
        }

        For(Account acc : trigger.new)
        {
            if(mapNameWiseAccount.containsKey(acc.name))
            {
                acc.Name.addError('Name already Exist ');
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must consistently use colons (`:`) to bind Apex variables into your SOQL queries. Here,

```
List<Account> lstAccount = [
    select Name, id, CreatedDate 
    from account 
    where name in :setName AND CreatedDate >= weekStart AND CreatedDate < weekEnd
];
```

you have correctly bound `setName` but missed the colon for `weekStart` and `weekEnd`.

Answer (score -2):

```
//Handler
public class RestrictDuplicateRecords {
    public static void restrictDuplicate(List<Account> acctList){
        List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
        Date myDate = Date.today();
        Date dd = myDate.toStartofWeek();
        Datetime weekStart = DateTime.newInstance(dd, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
        system.debug('weekStart'+weekStart);
        DateTime endWeek = weekStart.addDays(7);
        if(acctList != null){
            Set<String> accountName = new Set<String>();
            for(Account ac :acctList){ 
                accountName.add(ac.Name);
            }
            system.debug('test==='+accountName);
            accountList = [select Id, Name, CreatedDate from account where Name IN :accountName and CreatedDate >: weekStart and CreatedDate <: endWeek];
            system.debug('accountList====='+accountList);
            Map<String ,Account> mapVsName = new Map<String,Account>();
            for(Account acc: accountList)
            {
                if(acc.Name !=null){
                    mapVsName.put(acc.Name ,acc);
                }

            }

            for(Account acc : acctList)
            {
                if(acc.Name != null){
                    if(mapVsName.containsKey(acc.name))
                    {
                        acc.Name.addError('Name already Exist ');
                    } 
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

//Trigger
trigger TriggerOnAccount on Account (Before insert) {
         RestrictDuplicateRecords.restrictDuplicate(Trigger.new);

}
```

Comment: "Code dump" answers, which do not contain any explanation, provide limited value to the community and the asker, and tend to lead to a lot of back-and-forth in the comments. Instead of pasting code, please describe the issue and how it can be solved, including code to support the solution.